# Python process and overwrite external text file

Tags: python

I have a input text file as follows, this is saved as 12.txt:

> ```
> [(442, 165), (442, 184), (487, 165), (487, 184)],english
> ```

My aim is to remove all the special characters from this file and overwrite it : I am using below python script
:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2 as cv

#path = '/media/D/code/OCR/text-detection-ctpn/data/mlt_english+chinese/image'
gt_file = '12.txt'

with open(gt_file, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.replace("[", "")
        line = line.replace("(", "")
        line = line.replace(")", "")
        line = line.replace("]", "")
        line = line.replace(" ", "")

        f.write(line)
```

However it gives me this output:

> ```
> [(234, 162), (234, 183), (307, 162), (307, 183)],english
> 234,162,234,183,307,162,307,183,english
> ```

I dont want the output to be appended as it is as shows above I want the output to overwrite 12.txt. Filethat is 12.txt after running python script should look like this:

```
234,162,234,183,307,162,307,183,english
```

I have referred [Python replace and overwrite instead of appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469228/python-replace-and-overwrite-instead-of-appending/11469328) but there is some thing I am missing

Comment: Does using 'w+' instead of 'r+'as an option when opening the file not work?

Comment: @TUIlover `w+` truncates the file, so OP will not be able to read the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open temp file and read from file, remove old file and rename to new name

```
import os
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2 as cv

#path = '/media/D/code/OCR/text-detection-ctpn/data/mlt_english+chinese/image'
gt_file = '12.txt'
output = open("temp.txt","w")
with open(gt_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("[", "")
        line = line.replace("(", "")
        line = line.replace(")", "")
        line = line.replace("]", "")
        line = line.replace(" ", "")

        output.write(line)
output.close()
os.remove(gt_file) # remove old file
os.rename("temp.txt",gt_file) # rename as old file
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate the two processes, it's way cleaner.

```
#read and edit lines
to_write = [] #store edited lines
with open(gt_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        ...
        to_write.append(line)

#write back edited lines
with open(gt_file, 'w') as f:
    for line in to_write:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you file pointer has reached the end. Given a single line in text file, seek() and truncate() functions can be used to reproduce the results that you require.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import math

gt_file = '12.txt'

with open(gt_file, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.replace("[", "")
        line = line.replace("(", "")
        line = line.replace(")", "")
        line = line.replace("]", "")
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
file = open('test_file', 'r')
data = file.read()
file.close()

data = data.replace("[", "")
data = data.replace("(", "")
data = data.replace(")", "")
data = data.replace("]", "")
data = data.replace(" ", "")
print(data, file=open('test', 'w'))
```

Check if this works for you.