# My discord token checker is not deleting lines properly from a .txt file. (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make something that goes through a file called "tokens.txt" and removes all of the invalid discord user tokens. However, instead of deleting them, it keeps writing the same invalid tokens in the file and messing it up. I don't know why it is not properly deleting the tokens. Please let me know how to fix this. The code is below.

```
import requests
    
with open("tokens.txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        token=line.strip("\n")
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'authorization': token}
        url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/library"
        r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(token+" is valid")
        else:
            print("invalid token found "+token)
            tokenlines=f.readlines()
            for usertoken in tokenlines:
                if usertoken.strip("\n") != token:
                    f.write(usertoken)
                    print("invalid token automatically deleted")
```

Comment: maybe check if token is in upper or lower letters

Comment: they are all randomly upper or lower case if that is what you are talking about. What does that mean?

Comment: You're trying to iterate a file while already iterating it. Simplify your algorithm: iterate the input file, checking each token. If it is good, write it to the output file, if not, then simply dont write it to the output file.

Comment: @Supergamer5465 that means that if you try to match for example uppercase "A" with lowercase "a" you will not get match if I recall correctly. Use upper() or lower() functions to match case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either, find all the valid tokens, collect them into a list and then completely rewrite the file with the valid tokens.

```
import requests

valid_tokens = []
with open("tokens.txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        token=line.strip("\n")
        url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/library"
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(token + " is valid")
            valid_tokens.append(token)
        else:
            print("invalid token found "+token)
            # Could collect the invalid tokens here

with open("tokens.txt","w+") as f:
    for i in valid_tokens:
        f.write(i+"\n")
```

Otherwise, if you would rather replace the lines within the file, I would recommend looking at this post: [Replace and overwrite instead of appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469228/replace-and-overwrite-instead-of-appending/11469328#11469328).

Comment: And the effectiveness of this code is low I guess since you iterate file twice?