# Overwriting a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, overwrite

The code below works if the new data is written in a new txt file(test_02.txt).

```
with open("test_01.txt", "r+") as list_01:
    for i in list_01:
        if i[0] == "%":
            continue
        else:
            file = []
            file.append(i)
            with open("test_02.txt", "a") as list_02:
                list_02.writelines(file)
```

The file test_01.txt includes many lines and some of them start with %. I am trying to erase the lines start with % and overwrite the rest in the same txt file(test_01.txt).

How can I do that?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: suggest read all into memory, filter lines, then write back. if performance is not problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace and overwrite instead of appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469228/replace-and-overwrite-instead-of-appending)

Answer (score 1):

The code below resolved my problem.

```
import re

with open("test_01.txt", "r+") as list_01:
    data = list_01.read()
    list_01.seek(0)
    list_01.write(re.sub(r'^%.*\n?', '', data, flags=re.MULTILINE))
    list_01.truncate()
```