# How to overwrite a file in Python?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to overwrite a file. I based my answer on this [Read and overwrite a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424000/read-and-overwrite-a-file-in-python)

**To complete my codes:**

```
<select class="select compact expandable-list check-list" 
    ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="{% url envelopes:auto_sort %}?sort_by=custom">
        Custom order
    </option>
    <optgroup label="Category">
        <option value="{% url envelopes:auto_sort %}?sort_by=cat_asc">
            Ascending order
        </option>
        <option value="{% url envelopes:auto_sort %}?sort_by=cat_desc">
            Descending order
        </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

def auto_sort(request):
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by', None)
    if sort_by:
        temp_path = "{0}/file.txt".format(settings.SITE_ROOT) 

        f=open(temp_path,'r+')
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub('cat_asc', 'cat_desc', text)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        f.truncate()
        f.close();

        handle=open(temp_path,'w+')
        handle.write(sort_by)
        handle.close();

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('envelopes:editor'))
```

The output of my current codes:

The file contains `cat_desc` when I try rewrite again as `custom`. It rewrites as `customc`. Notice the `c` at the end, it must be `custom` only.

**Here is what I'm trying to achieve:**

1. I write on file, for example, `cat_desc`
2. If I want to write again, for example `custom`, the `cat_desc` must be removed and replaced with `custom`.

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub re.sub takes three string arguments 'pattern'/ 'replacement','string'. The fourth argument (your "text" argument) has to be a number specifying the count

Comment: What is the line with `re.sub` _supposed_ to do? The parameters are in different orders in the question and the traceback!

Comment: @gnibbler sorry I'm currently edit my codes now just to get the exact output

Comment: @RedBaron thanks, I update my answer now for the latest

Comment: This should work `text = re.sub('cat_desc', 'custom', text)`

Comment: Could you expand your question. 
1. Do you only write "cat_desc" or a whole line say "I am cat_desc"?
2. Your current code replaces cat_asc with cat_desc, "custom" does not come into picture. Maybe you should update the code too?

Comment: @RedBaron only `cat_desc`, `cat_asc`, and `custom`.

Comment: In that case regular expressions seem a bit of an overkill. Just wipe the file (Open in _w_ mode) and write what you want (You are anyways seeking to 0 to write)

Comment: @RedBaron can you post your answer. I really don't know about this. I just follow what I have search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your revised question, maybe something like this would be simpler

```
def auto_sort(request):
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by', None)
    if sort_by:
        temp_path = "{0}/file.txt".format(settings.SITE_ROOT) 
        #Set new_text to whatever you want based on your logic
        new_text = 'custom' 
        f=open(temp_path,'w')
        f.write(new_text)
        f.close();

        handle=open(temp_path,'w+')
        handle.write(sort_by)
        handle.close();

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('envelopes:editor'))
```

Comment: I get the error again `TypeError:an integer is required`. This is the error before.

Comment: remove the re.sub part. You don't need it

Answer (score 5):

New anwser ...

You're passing `text` as the 4th parameter of `re.sub`. This is supposed to be an `int`

```
Help on function sub in module re:

sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
    if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
    a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    a replacement string to be used.
```

---

old answer ...

Perhaps you are doing

```
from os import open
```

That is a different (lower level) open, you want to just use the builtin open (you don't need to import anything to use it)

Here is an example of doing it wrong and getting your error message

```
>>> from os import open
>>> open("some_path", "r+")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Also to overwrite the file, you need to open with "w+". "r" stands for read

Comment: I didn't use `from os import open`

Comment: @catherine, Ok. the problem isn't anything to do with overwriting the file, it's the wat you are using `re.sub`

Answer (score 5):

For your new question:

Trying to overwrite a file in-place is basically impossible, unless you're replacing byte strings with new byte strings of the exact same length. If you replace `'cat_desc'` with `'cat_asc'`, you're going to end up with `'cat_ascc'`.

What you're doing—opening it in `'r+'` mode, reading the whole thing, processing it, `seek`ing to 0, and writing the whole thing—does work. But it's not the best way to do things.

And at any rate, your problem is that immediately after you do this, you open the exact same path in `'w+'` mode (which truncates the file) and write something different. So, whatever you wrote is now gone.

The solution to that is… don't do that. I'm not sure what you were trying to do, but that probably isn't it.

Meanwhile, the best way to rewrite a file is the "atomic write temp and rename" idiom. This guarantees that you never corrupt the file, you either get the new file or still have the old one. It also means you don't have to keep the whole file around in memory; you can go bit by bit. And it's very simple… if you don't care about Windows. It works like this:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as outfile:
    with open(inpath) as infile:
        # copy from infile to outfile, changing things as you go
    os.rename(outfile.name, inpath)
```

Unfortunately, making this work on Windows is very painful. You can't move `outfile` while it's still open, and you can't access it outside the `with` statement, and on top of that you can't just overwrite `infile` with `outfile`; you have to do a complicated shuffle. And it's never going to be completely atomic, unless you're willing to require Vista/2008 and to call Win32 APIs directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with writing a file.

The traceback tells you that this line is the culprit:

```
File "/home/cath/src/envelopebudget/envelopebudget/settings/../apps/envelopes/views.py" in auto_sort
  357.         text = re.sub('cat_desc', 'cat_asc', 'custom', text)
```

If you look at the [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) method, you're calling it wrong:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

You're passing `'cat_desc'` as the `pattern`, `'cat_asc'` as the `repl`, `'custom'` as the `string`, and `text` as the `count`. That doesn't make any sense. `re.sub` expects the `count` to be an integer, and you've given it a string.

Comment: ok I already erase the custom and it works now. But what I'm trying to achieve is completely rewrite the file.

Comment: @catherine: OK, but if that's not working, you have a completely different problem, and you'll need to tell us what that is in detail, preferably in a new question.

Comment: Is it allow to create new question? My problem is overwrite the file which I put as title.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed, and even encouraged, to create a new question. These questions and answers are supposed to be useful for future searchers with similar problems. If you change your question as soon as you get an answer, the original question no longer exists, and the original answer no longer applies to the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy and paste the full error back

Try:

```
def auto_sort(request):
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by', None)
    if sort_by:
        temp_path = "{0}/file.txt".format(settings.SITE_ROOT) 
        f=open(temp_path,'r')
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub('custom', 'cat_asc', 'cat_desc', text)
        f.close();
        handle=open(temp_path,'w')
        handle.write(sort_by)
        handle.close();
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('envelopes:editor'))
```