# Command Line input for Python Script

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, yelp

**What I am trying to do here:**

I am trying to crawl yelp and get reviews from a particular page. However, I just want to modify this script to give "*Restaurant name*" as input.

For example:

User Input: 
**dennys-san-jose-5**

```
URL: http://www.yelp.com/biz/**dennys-san-jose-5**
```

**This is the actual script I am using right now:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
queries = 0
while queries <201:
    stringQ = str(queries)
    page = urlopen('http://www.yelp.com/biz/madison-square-park-new-york?start=' + stringQ)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    reviews = soup.findAll('p', attrs={'itemprop':'description'})
    authors = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'itemprop':'author'})

    flag = True
    indexOf = 1
    for review in reviews:
        dirtyEntry = str(review)
        while dirtyEntry.index('<') != -1:
            indexOf = dirtyEntry.index('<')
            endOf = dirtyEntry.index('>')
            if flag:
                dirtyEntry = dirtyEntry[endOf+1:]
                flag = False
            else:
                if(endOf+1 == len(dirtyEntry)):
                    cleanEntry = dirtyEntry[0:indexOf]
                    break
                else:
                    dirtyEntry = dirtyEntry[0:indexOf]+dirtyEntry[endOf+1:]
        f=open("reviews.txt", "a")
        f.write(cleanEntry)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close

    for author in authors:
        dirty = str(author)
        closing = dirty.index('>')
        dirty = dirty[closing+1:]
        opening = dirty.index('<')
        cleanEntry = dirty[0:opening]
        f=open("bla.txt", "a")
        f.write(cleanEntry)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close 
    queries = queries + 40
```

I am trying to read the restaurant name as parameter but it does not work somehow.

**What i did:**

```
while queries <201:
    stringQ = str(queries)
    page = urlopen('http://www.yelp.com/biz/' + stringQ)
```

But it does not work. I am giving **dennys-san-jose-5** as input from commandline (python script.py dennys-san-jose-5)

Please suggest me the issue here and how I can fix.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read arguments from the commandline, you can use [**argparse**](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html).

```
import argparse

#Define command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Yelp reviews.')
parser.add_argument("-p", "--page", dest="page", required=True, help="the page to parse")

#parse command line arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Your page name will now be in `args.page`. In this example, you would run the script like this:

```
>python script.py  -p dennys-san-jose-5
```

or

```
>python script.py --page dennys-san-jose-5
```

**Edit:**

- If your don't need any fancy stuff, and just want the raw command line input (like in a program that only you will be using, no need to validate input, etc):

  ```
  import sys
  print sys.argv
  ```
- If you want to prompt the user for a page name as the program is running: [Python: user input and commandline arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-user-input-and-commandline-arguments)

Comment: thanks for your comment. Is there anyway I could directly pass it without using -p or anything? Like, in java can't I pass `"dennys-san-jose-5"` and it gets appended to the end of the url `("http://www.yelp.com/biz/"+Query+)` like in java?

Sorry I am a beginner in python

Comment: To add to my comment, I have used sys.

`import sys
 stringQ = sys.argv[1]
 page = urlopen('http://www.yelp.com/biz/' + stringQ)` and it started to work!! Is it the right way?

Comment: If you don't need all the fancy functionality of argparse, you can get the raw command line arguments from `sys.argv`.

Comment: Thank you so much for enlightening! I learn't something today!! :)

I have one more question, all the reviews were getting appended everytime. But, I want to overwrite everytime(or create the same file again) everytime I search. `f=open("reviews.txt", "a")` however, i have modified it to `f=open("reviews.txt", "w")` but it doesn't work. Can you kindly suggest me why? Any alternatives?

Comment: @RockyBalBoa Please [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that (if it hasn'r already [been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424000/read-and-overwrite-a-file-in-python) somewere), so that others can find it too!