# Using fileinput (Python) for a search-and-replace while also sending messages to console

Tags: python, stdout

I have lines

```
for line in fileinput.input(file_full_path, inplace=True):
    newline, count = re.subn(search_str, replace_str, line.rstrip())
    # ... display some messages to console ...
    print newline # this is sent to the file_full_path
```

which are supposed to replace all occurrences of `search_str` in the file `file_full_path` and replace them with `replace_str`. The `fileinput` maps `stdout` to the given file. So, `print newline` and things sent to `sys.stdout` are sent to the file and not to the console.

I would like to, in the middle of the process, display some messages to console, e.g. I could show the portion of the line in which the replacement is going to occur, or some other messages, and then continue with the `print newline` into the file. How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Python docs:

> Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument inplace=1 is
>   passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file
>   is moved to a backup file and **standard output is directed to the input
>   file** (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it
>   will be replaced silently).

so you should write to stderr to display messages in the console, like this:

```
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(file_full_path, inplace=True):
    newline, count = re.subn(search_str, replace_str, line.rstrip())
    sys.stderr.write("your message here")
    print newline
```

Comment: Makes sense. Forgot about I could use `stderr` to communicate with the user. Thanks.

Comment: With the `write` method, you'd probably want `"your message here\n"`. Alternatively you could use `print >> sys.stderr, "your message here"`.