# python replace string in a file with open()

Tags: python

I am trying to have separate functions that will write an ip to a new line in an existing file, and the other to remove a string in the file if it exists. Currently the code I have come up with is this:

```
def writeebl(_ip):
    filepath = "ebl.txt"
    with open(filepath, mode='a') as ebl:
        ebl.write(_ip)
        ebl.write("\n")


def removeebl(_ip):
    filepath = "ebl.txt"
    with open(filepath, mode='r+') as f:
            readfile = f.read()
            if _ip in readfile:
                readfile = readfile.replace(_ip, "hi")
                f.write(readfile)

writeebl("10.10.10.11")
writeebl("20.20.20.20")
removeebl("20.20.20.20")
```

What I assume the output should be is a file with only `10.10.10.11`

First run file contents:

```
10.10.10.11
20.20.20.20
10.10.10.11
hi
(empty line)
```

Second run:

```
10.10.10.11
20.20.20.20
10.10.10.11
hi
10.10.10.11
hi
10.10.10.11
hi
```

I'm confused how this should be done. I've tried several different ways following some examples on stackoverflow, and so far I'm still stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not overwriting properly. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424000/read-and-overwrite-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You need to truncate the file before rewriting all of its content again in the `removeebl` function, so the stale content is wiped off before writing the updated one:

```
...
if _ip in readfile:
     readfile = readfile.replace(_ip, "hi")
     f.seek(0); f.truncate()
     f.write(readfile)
```