# How can I create a blacklist that filters out some lines in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that finds some lines in a file that starts with (doesn't need to be explicit), for example: "aaa some continued sentence in a line" or "iii another continued sentence" and write the exact lines it found in another file called blacklist.

For example, let's say my file is made from this funtion:

```
def writeletters(self):
    outf = "xfile.txt"
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f', 'g', 'h' ,'i']
    with open(outf, "w") as a:
        i = 0
        b = 5
        while i < len(alphabet):
            a.write((alphabet[i] * b) + '\n')
            i += 1
```

The output would be:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
```

How could I only get output with lines starting with "aaa" or "iii" sent or written to another file?

```
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
```

To try and achieve what I want, I wrote the blacklist function but it is obviously not working

```
  def blackList(self):
        filep = "xfile.txt"
        blacklist = ['aaa', 'iii']
        i = 0
        with open(filep) as bl:
            for line in bl:
                i + 1
                if any(s in line for s in blacklist):
                    print blacklist[i]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I will post some of what I've tried

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: "and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.)"

Comment: The line count from the output of the blackList function is fine but I am not getting the exact line content as one would expect. It only prints the first exact string from the list.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I fixed my blacklist function and posted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this pretty substantially

```
def blackList(self):
    filep = "xfile.txt"
    output = "output.txt"
    blacklist = ['aaa', 'iii']
    with open(filep, "r") as in_fh, open(output, "w") as out_fh:
        to_write = []
        for line in in_fh.readlines():
            for bad_entry in blacklist:
                if line.startswith(bad_entry):  # keep bad lines
                    to_write.append(line)
        out_fh.writelines(to_write)
```

For a sharp, but less-obvious approach, try this:

```
def blacklist_writer(input_file, output_file, blacklist):
    with open(input_file, "r") as in_fh, open(output_file, "w") as out_fh:
        # check l against blacklist in a nested generator
        out_fh.write("".join(l for l in in_fh.readlines() if [b for b in blacklist if l.startswith(b)]))
```

It creates a generator for which checks each line in `input_file` against another generator which makes a list of each line which matches the blacklist. If there are no matches, the list will be empty, and "falsey".

Comment: You never declared `lines`, but if you show writing to a file correctly with `lines`, you'll get my upvote. Using `str.startswith()` is definitely a more straight-forward approach than mine.

Comment: Good catch; `lines` should have been `to_write`.

Comment: to_write is still a list, you need to `'\n'.join(to_write)` in order to write it to a file. Also, `in_fh.readlines()` stores all of the file contents into memory, when you really want to read line by line with `for line in in_fh:`. Upvoted anyways because the logistics that solve the OP's problem is there, but please update your answer.

Comment: Yuck, thanks - sloppy coding without testing for me. Added a more exciting generator I was writing up (and tested).

Comment: @ti7 this is mostly what I was looking for I think. The only thing missing is removing the bad lines from the file being read.  I'll try to manage that

Comment: Excellent - You can just re-write the old file `if line.startswith(bad_entry): to_write_blacklisted.append(line) .. else: to_write_not_blacklisted.append(line)` .. take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424410/4541045) for how to open the file once and use truncation!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex, but the pattern on it will vary based on what you're trying to filter. If you literally want to filter out only lines starting with 3 a's or 3 i's, you can just use `re.match()`:

```
import re

regex_pattern = 'a{3}|i{3}'

def writeletters(regex_pattern):
    with open('xfile.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if re.match(regex_pattern, line):
                print line #replace this line with code to write to file
```

The `regex_pattern` is saying "any 3 in a row a's or i's". The `re.match()` will match any string *starting* with a given regex pattern.

Comment: Regular expressions are totally unnecessary here and you never addressed the actual problem.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 They're not unnecessary given the use case was "I need to match a string with so-and-so pattern", and what is the _actual_ problem then?

Comment: The pattern is "certain characters at the start of the string," and the OP has solved that part. Also, your expression will match strings like `'aiab'`, so that's wrong too.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You're correct about the regex matching 'aiab', so I'm fixing that now, but you're not correct in identifying the user's problem. That `any()` call doesn't match only start of the line, it would match that blacklist substring in any portion of the line. The user is specifically asking for lines that start with a specific substring.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi Thanks for your answer and I'm sure it's great but I just like to avoid regex since I'm still a python semi-noob. You got my upvote

Answer (score 0):

I realized my original attempt at solving this problem was close. I just had to print my line instead of my blacklist list so I'll post my solution as well. (stupid semi-noob mistake)

```
def blackList(self):
    filep = "xfile"
    blacklist = ['aaa', 'iii']
    out = "blacklist.txt"

    with open(filep) as bl, open(out, "w") as output:
        for line in bl:
            if any(s in line for s in blacklist):
                output.writelines(line)
```

A real blacklist that actually writes the original file without the blacklisted lines is as followed

```
def blackList(self):
    filep = "xfile"
    blacklist = ['aaa', 'iii']
    out = "blacklist.txt"

    with open(filep) as bl, open(out, "w") as output:
        for line in bl:
            if not any(s in line for s in blacklist):
                output.writelines(line)
```