# How to open a file, replace some strings, and save updates to the same file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop through all CSV files in a directory, do a find/replace, and save the results to the same file (same name).  It seems like this should be easy, but I seem to be missing something here.  Here is the code that I'm working with.

```
import glob
path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\downloads\\Products\\*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(str(fname))
    with open(str(fname), "w") as f:
        newText = f.read().replace('|', ',').replace(' ', '')
        f.write(newText)
```

I came across the link below, and tried the concepts listed there, but nothing has worked so far.

[How to open a file for both reading and writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/how-to-open-a-file-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Not posting as an answer as it doesn't use Python but if you have cygwin or bash for Windows you can achieve this with `sed` using the `-i` flag.

Comment: Can you try using "r+" instead of "w" when you open the file?

Comment: You need to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976014/10362396) answer. It will tell you how to open file in r/w mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a file for both reading and writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/how-to-open-a-file-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Comment: @Prune I think you are being a little over-the-top here, it's clear from the code and description what they trying to do..

Comment: Yeah ... figured it out ... by implementing the missing parts of the posting.  Note the lack of closure or down votes ...

Comment: this has already been well answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/1951298

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file using `'r+'` instead of `'w'`. See below:

```
import glob
path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\downloads\\Products\\*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(str(fname))
    with open(str(fname), "r+") as f:
        newText = f.read().replace('|', ',').replace(' ', '')
        f.write(newText)
```

Comment: Ah, I just saw this.  This is very, very close, but I want to overwrite what is in each file, not append the changes to the bottom of each file.  How can I open each one, replace a few strings, and write only the changes to each file, without including the original contents of each file?  Thanks.

Comment: Check this post out for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424000/read-and-overwrite-a-file-in-python

Comment: Yeap, that's it!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final (working) solution.

```
import glob
import fileinput
path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\downloads\\Products\\*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    #print(str(fname))
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read().replace(' ', '')
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        f.truncate()
```

Thanks for the tip, agaidis!!