# Convert spaces to newlines in text file using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
15.9 17.2 18.6 10.5
```

I want to edit this file in Python so that it looks like this:

```
15.9
17.2
18.6 
10.5
```

This means that I need to replace the space strings by newline strings and save the text.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
f = open("testfile.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if ' ' in line:
        line2 = line.replace(' ' , '\n')
    print(line2)
for i in line2:
    f.write(line2(i))
f.close
```

The print for `line2` is already working, but I don't get a new text file with  spaces replaced by newlines.

How can I fix the problem and produce the desired output?

Comment: firstly, you didn't `f.close()` your file. secondly, I believe you can directly write the line `f.write(line2)`, you don't need to iterate it.

Comment: also, you have two seperate for loops where in the first for loop, you keep overwriting `line2`. So the only line2 that gets written is the last one in the loop..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and overwrite a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424000/read-and-overwrite-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as r:
    with open("testfile_new.txt", "w") as w:
        w.write(r.read(.replace(' ' , '\n'))
```

Comment: Note that this slurps the entire file into memory. Also, you can use `with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as r, open('testfile_new.txt', 'w') as w:` and avoid a block. There's a syntax error as well: `r.read(.replace(' ' , '\n')` should be `r.read().replace(' ', '\n')`. Consider explaining why `with`... is advantageous over `open()` and/or offering a few words about what OP did wrong in their code attempt.

Comment: that will not work!!! it creates a new file and that not what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as read_file:
    with open("file2.txt", "w") as write_file:
        write_file.write(read_file.read().replace(" ", '\n'))
```

**Content of file1.txt:**

```
15.9 17.2 18.6 10.5
```

**Content of file2.txt:**

```
15.9
17.2
18.6
10.5
```

**NOTE:**

Or you can use the `split` and `join` method instead of replace.

```
write_file.write("\n".join(read_file.read().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this instead

```py
f = open("testfile.txt", "r")
text=f.read()
f.close()
f=open("testfile.txt", "w+")
text2=''
if ' ' in text:
    text2 = text.replace(' ' , '\n')
    print(text2)
    f.write(text2)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can try using string replace:

```
string = string.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

**Firstly:** f.close() is not there.

**Secondly:** try above code. It will replace spaces to new lines.

Comment: you can also try different combinations such as string.replace('\r', ' ' ).replace('\n', ' ')

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split` with `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()

with open("testfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(data.split()))
```